# android you must supply a layout_width attribute at line 7

Tags: android, xml

```
I have been trying to run this code but getting this error since last 1 week.
```

Please help!
I have already declared layout:width.
Tried with layout.width in sliding drawer and replacing dp wit dip but still got the same error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"> 

       <SlidingDrawer
           android:id="@+id/drawer"
           android:width="320dp"
           android:height="440dp"
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:content="@+id/content"
           android:handle="@+id/handle">

           <ImageView 
               android:id="@+id/handle"
               android:layout_width="48dp"
               android:layout_height="48dp"
               android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

           <AnalogClock 
               android:id="@+id/content"
               android:background="#D0A0A0"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
       </SlidingDrawer>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Layout tags are mandatory tags I believe. You have not supplied layout_width and layout_height to your `SlidingDrawer`

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Comment: @Akash: Please select this as right answer if it really helped you.